# Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, formatexception

I am doing the following conversion from string to int,

```
Convert.ToInt32("10D6DE", 16) -> works fine

but,

Convert.ToInt32("D0437X", 16) -> throws an format exception,
 "Additional non parsable characters at the end of string"
```

I am not sure whats wrong.

Comment: "I am not sure whats wrong." Well Convert.To* tries to convert the whole value, that's all. If you only want to convert part of the value, you'll need to work out how much of it to convert, and then convert that substring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> hexdigits: A sequence of hexadecimal digits from 0 through f, or 0
>   through F.

It won't parse your X at the end.